Enabling Inference for Data bricks endpoint
I'm trying to simply enable the inference table for my existing endpoint and not sure it says - Error occurred on one or more served entities.
and Im following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/model-serving/enable-model-serving-inference-tables
Output I need to that it shouldnt show this error since everything is enabled

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

check the Service logs databricks UI where you can find the cause of the issue.

This error occurs due to failed deployment of served entity.
One of your served entity or both is failed while deploying them.
Below are few things you need to check.

Check the model is correctly registered in Databricks Model Registry
The error occurs if there are issues with the specific version of the model. Make sure that the model is properly logged, and that there are no mismatches or inconsistencies between versions.
Verify that the model dependencies are properly installed and specified in the serving environment. Sometimes, issues can arise due to missing libraries or incompatible package versions.
Make sure  that you have correct permissions to enable the inference table and serve the model.

Check this documentation for multi model serving in single endpoint.

You can not serve different model types in a single endpoint. For example you can not serve a custom model and an external model in the same endpoint.

Here, there some conditions and requirements you need to meet to serve multi model please go through it.
